# Проблема с корректностью отражения страницы html загруженной в портал

Tags: html

Проблема с корректностью отражения страницы html загруженной в портал (портал развернут локально). Html страница при развертывании в браузере загружается нормально, но при загрузке в портал картинка не отображается-выдает ошибку изображения.Подскажите в чем причина.

Comment: извините, но повторюсь, отдел ЭКСТРАСЕНСОВ до сих пор в отпуске!

Comment: картинка не отображается-выдает ошибку, что бы это могло бы значить?.. :D

Comment: Скорее всего, нужно проявить терпение и она там через неделю появится, вырастет, у неё просто корни еще не образовались и её забыли полить водой :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope сегодня на ХК поток таких)))

Comment: А я писал коммент [тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/69844/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=69860#69860)

Comment: экстрасенсы в отпуске, зато слет петросянов удался =)

Comment: Что тут непонятного?!портал работает по принципу нипеля - туда изображение - оттуда...(в изначальном варианте: "туда дуй - оттуда ..."). Надо срочно закрыть этот портал и пообещать себе, что больше никогда-никогда его не откроете!

Answer (score 1):

Как обнаружить ошибку:

1. Смотрите адрес картинки.
2. Ищете ее на локальном хосте.
3. Не находите.
4. Охреневаете.
5. Переписываете код портала.

Вроде, все. Ах, да: ..., PROFIT!